# Activity statistics in Google Analytics v4

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to integrate the v4 inside an Android application using [THIS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) guide, and I want simple Activity stats.
In onStart() method of the Activity I want to monitor, which one of these should I put:

```
Tracker t = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getTracker();

// Set screen name.
// Where path is a String representing the screen name.
t.setScreenName("ListActivity");

// Send a screen view.
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

OR:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this)
```

What is the difference between these two? What should I put inside onStop()?

Thanks.